# Search for Linux Process (PID) using string query from Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, pid

In Linux , I use below query to get the process id (PID) for process with name **serverManager**

```
ps -ef | grep serverManager
```

I need to perform the same activity in Ansible? I tried searching the API docs, but no luck

Can anyone tell me approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in ansible you can do any command you'd do in terminal with the [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) module. However with the command you provided you can't retrieve the pid, I suggest you use `pgrep`.

so the code should be

```
- shell: pgrep serverManager
  register: servermanager_pid
```

Comment: Just got into a complex scenario, how to register multiple pids?

Comment: if you pass `servermanager_pid` to a task `debug` that would help you to understand how to do. hint: all pids are returned in `servermanager_pid.stdout_lines`